# While uploading an video file using FileUpload control it is giving an error like HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request

Tags: .net

While uploading an video file using FileUpload control it is giving an error like **HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request**

Answer (score 0):

Check on your server the limit of file upload and POST request